# Spring Security Returning Anonymous user after Success Authentication-SpringBoot 3.0.6 Spring Security 6.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am working with Spring Boot 3.0.6 and Spring Security 6.x. I set the SecurityContextHolder with my Authentication ( using UserNameAndPasswordAuthenticationToken), but when I use Postman to test the userName I put in JWT the result is **anonymousUser**.

Here is my JwtFilter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Resource
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Resource
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(jwt)){
            jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwt);
            String userName = jwtTokenUtil.getUserNameFromToken(jwt);
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

            if (userDetails != null && userDetails instanceof CustomUserDetails) {
                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                LOG.info("Authentication has user name : " + ((UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername()); // I log the result in here for you to check out that the Security Context Holder has already set with authentication.
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(bearerToken == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my Web Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{
    @Resource
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Resource(name = "jwtService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/n/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/r/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I use FilterRegistrationBean to assign my custom JWT filter for some specific path:

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(){
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> jwtFilterRegistration(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/api/auth/r/*");
        registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registration.setName("Jwt Filter");
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        registration.setMatchAfter(false);
        registration.setEnabled(true);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

And this is my Authentication Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Resource
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Resource
    private UserFacades userFacades;

    @Resource
    private SignInValidation signInValidation;

    @Resource(name = "jwtService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/n/create-user")
    @ResponseBody
    public GlobalMessage createNewCustomer(@RequestBody CreateNewUserRequest request){
        UserValidation.validateRegisterInfo(request.getUserName(), request.getPassword());
        UserValidation.validateEmail(request.getEmail());
        return userFacades.createNewCustomer(request);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/n/login")
    public JWTRespond signIn(@RequestBody SignInRequest request){
        UserValidation.validateRegisterInfo(request.getUserName(), request.getPassword());

        signInValidation.validateSignInInfo(request.getUserName(), request.getPassword());

        CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUserName());

        String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(user);
        Date expirationDate = jwtTokenUtil.getExpirationDateFromToken(jwt);
        return new JWTRespond(jwt,expirationDate);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/r/testing")
    public String testing(){
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String){
            return "No User Details : " + (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }else if(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails){
            return "User Details : " + ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        }
        return "No thing";
    }

}
```

The Log in terminal show that The Security Context Holder has Authentication already:

[image]

Here is the result when I use PostMan for url : **http://localhost:9000/api/auth/r/testing**

[image]

Comment: Why do you have this? `.requestMatchers("/api/auth/r/**").permitAll()`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I add that line since I want to separate for the future Authority in my Controller after I have fixed this issue. The api start with /api/*/n means you don't need specific role to use this api. While /api/*/r mean you need some role to access this api

Comment: Who close this question? I have the answer and I want to answer this question and then someone close this question?